# Binary deserialization fixups mismatch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, deserialization

Been trying to deserialize a legacy binary file by reconstructing the data structures.

Code was pretty standard, no special cases. I thought I was done but I still kept receiving this error

> The ObjectManager found an invalid number of fixups. This usually indicates a problem in the Formatter

Relevant info:

- I was working in a submodule with its own assembly
- Namespaces were complete and coherent
- Same versions of .Net being used

Answer (score 0):

After a very long investigation I attempted to save the binary result of the decompression before proceeding with the deserialization.

I have noticed that although all namespaces were coherent, the original data structure was being hosted within the regular Unity assembly (`Assembly-CSharp`), while my target data structure was being hosted within a submodule with its own assembly.

Just be mindful of the fact that when serializing/deserializing assembly information is carried over!